# Using apple script to find out and compare process path by PID

Tags: macos, applescript

I am using Apple Script to find the process PID by name, like ...

```
set appName to "KKK"

tell application "System Events"
     set processPID to (unix id of processes whose name is appName)
end tell
```

With this script, I can know about PIDs of all processes which name is "KKK".

But I have a question here.

For example, there has three "KKK" process,  "/FolderA/KKK", "FolderB/KKK", "FolderC/KKK"

I want to kill the process of "/FolderA/KKK", so I need to know which PID is belong to "/FolderA/KKK".

After run my script, I can get three PIDs, what can I actually do in Apple Script to distinguish which PID is what I want?  (Maybe to get the process path by PID?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `name` check for the `path` of the application, this is an example checking for `Messages.app`.

```
set appPath to "/Applications/Messages.app"

tell application "System Events"
    set processPID to (unix id of 1st process whose POSIX path of application file is appPath)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It also can be done using the following:

```
do shell script "kill -9 $(ps -x | awk '/[F]olderA\\/KKK/{print $1}')"
```

You can also add `; exit 0` to the end to eat an error if the app isn't running and have no need to check or trap otherwise:

```
do shell script "kill -9 $(ps -x | awk '/[F]olderA\\/KKK/{print $1}'); exit 0"
```